# BeautifulSoup Matching on Incorrect Class

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working with HTML that looks like the below:

```
<td class="hidden-xs BuildingUnit-price" data-sort-value="625000">
<span class="price">$625,000  </span>
</td>
<td class="hidden-xs BuildingUnit-bedrooms" data-sort-value="4.0">
        4 rooms, 2 beds
      </td>
<td class="hidden-xs BuildingUnit-bathrooms">
        5 baths
      </td>
<td class="hidden-xs" data-sort-value="1">
    1 bath
  </td>
```

I wrote the script below to identify the td tags that have the class "hidden-xs" in order to pull the number of bathrooms for real estate listings, but it is matching on the "hidden-xs BuildingUnit-price" class as well. How can I correct this?

```
#Extract the number of baths
import re
lst_baths=list()
baths=soup.find_all("td", class_=["hidden-xs"])  
bath_lines=[td.get_text().strip() for td in baths]
pattern=re.compile(r'(\d{1})\D*(bath|baths)$')
for bath in bath_lines:
    match=pattern.match(bath)
    if match:
        lst_baths.append(bath.split()[0])
```

For example, as it's currently written, my code picks up the "5 bathrooms" line, but I only want it to pick up the "1 bath" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to test the class of each match:

```
#Extract the baths
lst_baths=list()
temp_lst=list()
baths=soup.find_all("td", class_=["hidden-xs"])
for item in baths:
    if item['class']==['hidden-xs']:
        temp_lst.append(item)
    else:
        pass
bath_lines=[td.get_text().strip() for td in temp_lst]
pattern=re.compile(r'(\d{1})\D*(bath|baths)$')
for bath in bath_lines:
    match=pattern.match(bath)
    if match:
        lst_baths.append(bath.split()[0])
```